# SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014

I have set up SSRS on MS SQL 2014 Dev Edition using the ReportServer built in account as the *Service Account*.

My machine name is: POUYASAGER
My local login is pyous
I have given the ReportServer account full permissions to:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services
```

I have checked that SecureConnectionLevel is set to 0 in the rsreportserver.config file.

I set up ReportServer as the virtual directory so that the Report Server Web Service URLs would be: http://POUYASAGER:80/ReportServer

When I click on the link in the **Reporting Services Configuration Manager** which is the same as above, I get:

The permissions granted to user 'POUYASAGER\pyous' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

When I navigate to: http://127.0.0.1:80/ReportServer, an authentication pop-up asks for a username and password.

When I navigate to the reports manager using: http://pouyasager:80/Reports, I get:
Error
Unable to connect to the remote server

How can I get SSRS working properly?

EDIT: I added "localhost" to the host headers and still got the same error.
EDIT: Using Chrome with Admin permissions, I navigate to http://localhost:80/ReportServer with the same results.

Comment: Check the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132812/the-permissions-granted-to-user-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation

Comment: I can't get to the reports tab as indicated by that link. http://pouyasager/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx for me results in "Error:
Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: It should just be http://localhost/reports but you need to navigate to it as local admin, thus opening IE as administrator.

Comment: I started Chrome as admin and got: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: @PouyaYousefi refer to [this link from SSC](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/simon_says/2010/01/07/error-rsaccessdenied-the-permissions-granted-to-user-toma-pc-toma-are-insufficient-for-performing-this-operation/) to see if it helps.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 or 8? Add your local account to sql server. pouyasager\pyous. Keep it simple and grant yourself sys admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the account you are logging in on your OS will allow for you to connect to SSRS. You are provided with a 403 error message directly related to an access denied. The type of access being denied here is at the database level, mainly for the Reportserver$ database. Your OS login is unable to personify NT SERVICE since it does not have a login on the server and guest account being probably disabled.

Additionally, verify the following:
'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\V2.0.050727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'. (or where ever your .NET framework is installed on your machine)

Right click on the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" and select properties->secutity.

See if the "NETWORK SERVICE" is already part of the "User/Group" section. If not add it by typing "Network Service".
If it's already there then grant the write permissions.

Comment: Yes. This is a big annoyance I have run into after a new SSRS install as well.  Apparently, the only way to access the security settings after a new install is as a local admin.  Don't just add the account locally, grant local administrator to it as well.  Once you are a local admin, you should be able to launch into the app, add other users and then if you want, remove the local admin privileges.